# Why this code does not work to focus on desired div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below should focus on the second div but it does not work what is wrong in this code?

```js
$(function(){
    $("#two").focus();
});
```

```css
body{color:white;}
#fis{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:red;}
#two{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:green;}
#thr{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<div id="fis">hello
</div>
<div id='two'>mr
</div>
<div id='thr'>john
</div
```

Comment: You cant focus a `div` unless it has a `tabindex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `tabindex` for that.

```
<div id='two' tabindex='1'>mr
</div>
```

Check updated snippet;

```js
$(function(){
    $("#two").focus();
});
```

```css
body{color:white;}
#fis{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:red;}
#two{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:green;}
#thr{height:600px;width: 60px;background-color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fis">hello
</div>
<div id='two' tabindex='1'>mr
</div>
<div id='thr'>john
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QAkGV/190/)**